# Many to Many Relatioship Mysql and Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables in Mysql : Annonce and User, my problem is that the User can comment Annonce, like Annonce or share it, so i want to know if i want to display to user annonces thaht he likes or commented how to filter it ? can i add a third column in Associative Table between User an Annonce which will be Action for example ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create new tables so they relate `User` and `Annonce` in every way you want. There should be 3:

`Comment(user_id, annonce_id, comment)`

`Like(user_id,annonce_id)`

`Share(user_id, annonce_id, maybe_other_attributes)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you help me in my other post please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162746/multiple-foreign-key-from-the-same-table

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look, but first, if the answer solved your problem please accept it @abdel.ouam